# How do I find unique characters in users input?

Tags: string

This algorithm creates a string by taking each unique character in the message in the order they first appear and putting that letter and the number of times it appears in the original message into the shortened string. Your algorithm should ignore any spaces in the message, and any characters which it has already put into the shortened string. For example, the string "I will arrive in Mississippi really soon" becomes "8i1w4l2a3r1v2e2n1m5s2p1y2o".

Here's my code for determining how many unique characters there are. I'm having trouble creating the nested loop to scan the whole string. Help pls!!

```
 boolean used = false;
  for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){
    if (input.substring(j,j+1).equals(ltr)){
      used = true;
    }
  }
  if (!used){
    num++;
    int count = 0; 
    for(int k=i; k<input.length(); k++){
      if(input.substring(k,k+1).equals(ltr))
        count++;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that. Maybe your nested loop is not right.

### Do you use nested loop?

---

your code is like this: `for(){} for(){}`

---

not `for(){ for(){ }}`

---

Answer (score 0):

your program just scan the current character and the next character in position ! to find it is unique or not that's the problem
here your problem exactly

```
if (input.substring(j,j+1).equals(ltr)){
```

Comment: i can help you to find the solution !